# PHP : Get Image Path and Store to Database

Tags: php, sql

I have problem. Please take a look to my main.php and upload.php

main.php

```
<?php
include "include/db_connection.php";
$id     = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";

if ($id=="") {
        echo "<script>alert('Pilih Mahasiswa yang Ingin Unggah Berkas!');</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT mahasiswa.nim, mahasiswa.nama, mahasiswa.jurusan 
                              FROM mahasiswa 
                              WHERE mahasiswa.nim = '$id'");
        while ($hisal=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                    $nim    = $hisal['nim'];
                    $nama   = $hisal['nama'];
                    $jur    = $hisal['jurusan'];
                }   
            }
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>NIM</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $nim;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nama</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $nama;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jurusan</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $jur;?></td>
    </tr>
</table><br><br>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="?page=upload">
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Jenis Berkas</td>
            <td align="center">Berkas</td>
            <td align="center">Aksi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Foto</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="file" name="foto" accept="image/jpeg"></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo"<a href='?page=prosesUbah2&id=$hisal[nim];'>Ubah</a> | 
                           <a href='?page=prosesHapus2&id=$id' onclick='return confirm(\"Anda yakin ingin menghapus berkas dari nim $id ?\")'>Hapus</a>"
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Scan KTM</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="file" name="ktm" accept="image/jpeg"></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo"<a href='?page=prosesUbah2&id=$id'>Ubah</a> | 
                           <a href='?page=prosesHapus2&id=$id' onclick='return confirm(\"Anda yakin ingin menghapus berkas dari nim $id ?\")'>Hapus</a>"
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Unggah" id="Unggah" value="Unggah Berkas"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
include "include/db_connection.php";
$id     = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$file       = "uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];

if ($_FILES["foto"]["error"] > 0 && $id==""){
    echo "<script>alert('Upload Failed')</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUE ('','','','','','','$file','','') WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");

        if ($sql){
            echo "<script>alert('Upload Gambar Sukses')</script>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
            } else{
                echo "<script>alert('Upload Failed')</script>";
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
                }
        }

?>
```

Image file copied to uploads folder but the path of it is not store on the database. When i click "Unggah Berkas" button, the alert says "Upload Failed" but Image copied to uploads folder. Can you help me? Thanks anyway.

**UPDATE**

i already change this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="?page=upload&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">

     //my code

</form>
```

and this

```
    <?php
    include "include/db_connection.php";
    $id         = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
    $file       = "uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];

    if ($_FILES["foto"]["error"] > 0 || $id==""){
        echo "<script>alert('Upload Failed')</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
            $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUE ('','','','','','','$file','','') WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");    
            } 
?>
```

and still not store into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path couldn't get stored in the table because you didn't send `id` in the URL. Your `<form>` tag should be like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">

    // your code

</form>
```

**Update:**

And also change your `if` condition like this:

```
if($_FILES["foto"]["error"] > 0 || $id==""){

    // error

}else {

    // no error

}
```

**Re-edited:**

This would be your directory structure:

```
include
    |--db_connection.php
uploadform
    |--main.php
    |--upload.php
uploads
```

**main.php**

Suppose user's id 12, then you have to call main.php like this, **main.php?id=12**

```
<?php
    require_once("../include/db_connection.php");
    $id     = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";

    if ($id=="") {
            echo "<script>alert('Pilih Mahasiswa yang Ingin Unggah Berkas!');</script>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
        } else {
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT mahasiswa.nim, mahasiswa.nama, mahasiswa.jurusan 
                                  FROM mahasiswa 
                                  WHERE mahasiswa.nim = '$id'");
            while ($hisal=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $nim    = $hisal['nim'];
                $nama   = $hisal['nama'];
                $jur    = $hisal['jurusan'];
            }   
    }
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>NIM</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $nim;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nama</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $nama;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jurusan</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $jur;?></td>
    </tr>
</table><br><br>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Jenis Berkas</td>
            <td align="center">Berkas</td>
            <td align="center">Aksi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Foto</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="file" name="foto" accept="image/jpeg"></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo"<a href='?page=prosesUbah2&id=$hisal[nim];'>Ubah</a> | 
                           <a href='?page=prosesHapus2&id=$id' onclick='return confirm(\"Anda yakin ingin menghapus berkas dari nim $id ?\")'>Hapus</a>"
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">Scan KTM</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="file" name="ktm" accept="image/jpeg"></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo"<a href='?page=prosesUbah2&id=$id'>Ubah</a> | 
                           <a href='?page=prosesHapus2&id=$id' onclick='return confirm(\"Anda yakin ingin menghapus berkas dari nim $id ?\")'>Hapus</a>"
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Unggah" id="Unggah" value="Unggah Berkas"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

    require_once("../include/db_connection.php");
    $id     = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
    $file       = "uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];

    if ($_FILES["foto"]["error"] > 0 || $id==""){
        echo "<script>alert('Upload Failed')</script>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], "../uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUE ('','','','','','','$file','','') WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");

        if ($sql){
            echo "<script>alert('Upload Gambar Sukses')</script>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
        } else{
            echo "<script>alert('Upload Failed')</script>";
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: still not working sir, alert still says upload failed.

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="?page=upload&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">

// my code
</form>

and

if ($_FILES["foto"]["error"] > 0 || $id==""){
 echo "<script>alert('Upload Failedl')</script>";
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?page=tugas2'>";
 } else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/".$_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
  $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUE ('','','','','','','$file','','') WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'"); 
  }

Comment: @PhaskalRolando Make sure you're getting `id` value at the top of **main.php** (`$id     = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";`)

Comment: @PhaskalRolando you're supposed to call **main.php** like this, `main.php?id=34`, so that it can get `id` value using superglobal `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: @PhaskalRolando And please change your action part from `action="?page=upload&id=<?php echo $id; ?>"` to `action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"`

Comment: @PhaskalRolando are you getting right `$id` using `$_GET['id']` on **main.php**?

Comment: yep. if i change the form action to your suggest, 'action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"' instead of mine, it comes more error sir. i put upload.php and main.php inside uploadform folder and db_connection on include folder, when i try to change the include to 'include "../include/db_connection.php";' is says cant copy the image because there is no uploads folder inside uploadform folder

Comment: @PhaskalRolando Okay, let me break down the problem for you. The reason you are able to upload images but couldn't save path in the database is because your `$id` field is empty in your SQL query. By the way, where is your `uploads` folder?

Comment: that was exactly what i thought, here the screenshot [prntscr](http://prntscr.com/9b0ynd). inside uploadform folder : upload.php, main.php. inside include folder: db_connection.

Comment: @PhaskalRolando and may I know what error are you getting after changing `action` and `include` part?

Comment: this [error](http://prntscr.com/9b131n). it keeps looping and i need to shut down my google chrome to close that. nvm i've changed the uploadform folder name to unggah_berkas. i changed the name because i use english on this site. but what inside is still same

Comment: @PhaskalRolando Please see the **re-edited** section of my answer.

Comment: i dont get it sir, sorry but what do you mean by this? "then you have to call main.php like this, main.php?id=12" in my case, i take the `id` from database. its automatic. how do i call `main.php` like `main.php?id=12` ?

Comment: @PhaskalRolando What I mean is, if your user's id is 12 then on your browser window you should type **main.php?id=12** instead of just **main.php**

Comment: @PhaskalRolando here's a rough example, **http://localhost/tugas2/uploadform/main.php?id=12**

Comment: @PhaskalRolando yes, type it on your browser, but replace `id` by your actual user's id.

Comment: @PhaskalRolando Here's an example for you, [http://prntscr.com/9b26s8](http://prntscr.com/9b26s8)

Comment: none of your solution is solve my problem sir but thanks anyway. your solution basicly the same code of mine but in a different way. i've made a mistake with my query. this is the old query `$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUE ('','','','','','','$file','','') WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");` and this is the new one `$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE mahasiswa SET foto='$foto' WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");` and its done. just change from `INSERT INTO` to `UPDATE SET`. i just figure it out because the data already store in database from pervious page and `main.php` page is just to add an image.

Answer (score 0):

Just change query from

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUE ('','','','','','','$file','','') WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");
```

to

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE mahasiswa SET foto='$foto' WHERE mahasiswa.nim='$id'");
```